# In finite dimensional space, bounded means totally bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, geometric-topology

In a normed ($\ell_q, 1 \leq q$ ) linear finite dimensional space $\mathbb R^n$, does bounded means totally bounded? What other hypothesis do I need here?

Comment: Are you referring to subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need additional hypotheses.  An infinite set with the discrete metric is bounded but not totally bounded.  Did you have some constraint on the metric in mind?

Comment: Oh, you are right. Can you explain it in these different cases?

Comment: Under the discrete metric, the entire space is contained in an open ball with radius $2$ (or any specific radius greater than $1$).  However, since every point is distance $1$ from every other point, it takes infinitely many open balls of radius $1/2$ (or any specific positive radius less than one) to cover the space, so the space cannot be totally bounded.